# Verifying a twitter account without authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

My web app was previously using the following function to check the existence of a twitter account:

```
var checkTwitter = function(username){

     $.ajax({
      url: 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='+username+'&count=1&suppress_response_codes=true&callback=?',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data, success){
      if(data.error){
                  //gone bad code
      } else {
                  //gone good code

      }
}});
  }
```

Which has been happily working for a month or two. Now the url returns:

```
{"error":"Not found","request":"\/statuses\/user_timeline.json?screen_name=mildfuzz&count=1&suppress_response_codes=true&callback=?"}
```

when checking for my own twitter account (@mildfuzz).

What's gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter recently changed their API rules maybe it is coz of that?

Try changing to https.

According to [Twitter Dev](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) use HTTPS

And you must have an authentication [context](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth#user-context).

`https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=2`

Comment: Place this as a comment. This is not an answer.

Comment: I cant comment on the question. I need to get myself 15 rep points for  that genius!

Answer (score 1):

You should also change your success function to :

```
if(data="[]" || data.error || data.errors){
      //gone bad code
} else {
      //gone good code
}
```

error (when not authorised) : https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=test&count=2

errors (when user does not exist): https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=qsdsqdq&count=2

Also when the user does not exist, it can return an empty array (although i have no idea why) : https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=dsf&count=2

Comment: The returned response posted by OP states otherwise: `{"error":"Not found",`

Comment: If you check the link provided above by CreativeSyco and fill in a username that does not exist, you receive data saying 'errors' . Have a look at this : https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=sdjklsjqksd&count=2   that user does not exist , and the data return is == {"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}   . hence why i say 'also' change...

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup
this link fixes it. Twitter now have a function for simply looking a user up, which does not require authentication.